# How to make an svg text's position depend on another text's position?

Tags: css, svg

Here is an SVG with two texts one below the other. I need to keep the first text always at a fixed position from the next text, And it would be better if this gap could be responsive, that is, it should decrease if size of svg is reduced, and increase accordingly as well.
I searched a lot and found a lot of answers that went over my head.
Cant we do something that looks like `y=".text--line2.y"` ?

Here is the svg:

```css
.text--line {
  font-size: .5em;
}

svg {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 5em/1 Arial;
}

.text-copy {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 7% 28%;
  stroke-width: 3px;
   
}
.text-copy:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: #cccccc;
  stroke-dashoffset: 7%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-dashoffset: 14%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(3) {
  stroke: #eeeeee;
  stroke-dashoffset: 21%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(4) {
  stroke: #aaaaaa;
  stroke-dashoffset: 28%;
}
.text-copy:nth-child(5) {
  stroke: #bbbbbb;
  stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stroke-offset {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
}

@keyframes stroke-offset {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800px 600px">
  <symbol id="s-text">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="42%" class="text--line" y="40%">
      sdsds
    </text>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="68%" class="text--line2">
     gfgfg
    </text>
    
  </symbol>
  
  <g class="g-ants">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>     
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#s-text" class="text-copy"></use>     
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position parts of a string with the [`dx` and `dy`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TSpanElementDXAttribute) attributes. The attribute describes the position of the next tspan **relative to the end** of the previous one. Imagine it like this: initially, "abcde" and "fghij" would be rendered in one line, next to each other. Setting a dx/dy then moves the "fghij" by that amount.

Remember that whitespace also results in a horizontal advance. If you use percentage values, they are in relation to the size of the viewport (the `<svg>` *element*, not its viewBox).

```css
.text--line {
  font-size: .5em;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 5em/1 Arial;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800px 600px">
    <text text-anchor="middle">
      <tspan x="42%" y="40%" class="text--line">abcde</tspan><tspan
             dx="-7%" dy="30%" class="text--line2">fghij</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: My problem is that on different screen sizes, the gap between both spans is either too much or they overlap, :( can we make the values of dx and dy dependent on the window size as well?

Comment: You can express the values in all [length units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#lengths) that CSS understands. The only thing that won't work is the `calc()` function. For viewport units `vw`, `vh`, there may be some browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Its working sir. Only it was not working on blogger due to certain stylings of some parent elements. But anyways I was a looking for a general answer not just blogger, so dx and dy work perfectly when I am doing it on pages where I am aware of styles of all elements unlike blogger.